# python: list index out of range in reducer

Tags: python, stdin

I'm writing the reduce part of my mapreduce program and I am getting a 'list index out of range' in the line SplitLine = [1]. Why is this? I was fairly sure this was correct.

```
import sys

cKey = ""
cList = []
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        splitLine = line.split("\t")

        key = splitLine[0]
        value = splitLine[1]

....
```

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: There was a line with no \t. It it split into a 1-list which has no [1].

Comment: Does the file have any blank lines?

Comment: yes, a bunch. How do I go about that? Should I split by space instead?

Comment: Use `line.split()` without arguments.  This will split on any white space.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer I tried that and sadly got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access splitLine[1] when there is no [1] entry. Most likely, you have either blank lines or lines that have no \t in it.

A possible solution would be to ignore entries that have less than 2 columns:

```
import sys

cKey = ""
cList = []
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip()
    splitLine = line.split("\t")

    if len(splitLine) > 1:
      key = splitLine[0]
      value = splitLine[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do 2 things:

1. Filter out blank lines at the outset    `if not re.match(r'^\s*$', line):`
2. For non blank lines add a default value for border cases with no tabs (blank space " " in this case) `line+"\t "`

Sample code:

```
import sys

cKey = ""
cList = []
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

for line in lines:
    # line is empty (has only the following: \t\n\r and whitespace)
    if not re.match(r'^\s*$', line):
        # add extra delimiter '\t' and default value ' ' to be safe
        line = line+"\t "
        splitLine = line.split("\t")

        key = splitLine[0]
        # strip any  blank spaces at end
        value = splitLine[1].rstrip()
```